# What's the complexity of the following code?

Tags: java, algorithm, math, complexity-theory, time-complexity

According to this code:

```
for (int i=1; i<=N; i*=2)
{
  for (int j=1;j<=i;j++)
  {
    System.out.println("The value for i is "+i+" and the value for j is "+j);
  }
}
```

The first `for-loop` will run `log(n)` times,
at first I thought of `2n-1` for the second `for-loop`, but it doesn't work for odd numbers.

Any ideas? :)

Comment: It's the amount of times the first loop gets executed (`log(n)`) multiplied by the amount of times the second loops gets executed (`i`).

Comment: Do you want the asymptotic complexity or the number of iterations? Asymptotic is n*log(n)

Comment: I need to think about the number of iterations for any line, than find the O notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first for loop has got `i` as a series:

[image]

First loop stops when last element of this series is biger or equal N:

[image]

`x` stands for how many times first loop execute. Now we are trying to find `x`:

[image]

where

[image]

Yes it is as you say:

> The first for-loop will run log(n) times

The second for loop body runs as a sum:

[image]

**It is proof that your algorithm has O(n) complexity**

Your printing occurs `2N-1` times if N is one of: `1, 2, 4, 8, ... , 2^n`

---

It is superficially analysis but it do the work.

Answer (score 4):

- When `i = 1`, the inner loop will run 1 times
- When `i = 2`, the inner loop will run 2 times
- When `i = 4`, the inner loop will run 4 times
- ...
- When `i = N`, the inner loop will run N times

The print statement is executed `1 + ... + N/4 + N/2 + N` times, which is O(n).

Comment: `O(n)` is right, but this proof (this form of proof) works only for `2^n - 1`

Comment: @DmitryGinzburg Bounding from above and below by the next power of 2 will do.

Comment: @G.Bach worth mentioning in  answer